# Using glossaries-extra some abbreviations are not expanded in first use while others are

Tags: glossaries, acronyms, glossaries-extra

I am currently writing a thesis in Overleaf and am trying to manage my abbreviations using the glossaries-extra package. There are currently 14 abbreviations used throughout the text. I am using the long-short style which should show "long (short)" for the first use and then just "short" for the following uses. Out of the 14 abbreviations only 12 of them does this. The two others only show the short variant even at first use.

I am also using a script that allows the abbreviations to havew lower case letters for the expanded first use in the text while the expanded variant in the list of abbreviations have upper case first letters.

This is how the abbreviations are set up:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossdesc}{firstuc} % Used for upper case in list.
\glssetcategoryattribute{abbreviation}{glossdesc}{title} % Used for upper case in list.
\makeglossaries
\setglossarystyle{list}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short}

\begin{document}

\newabbreviation{PUR}{PUR}{polyuretan} % Does not expand at first use
\newabbreviation{HDPE}{HDPE}{hoytetthets polyeten}
\newabbreviation{CMS}{CMS}{corrosion management system}
\newabbreviation{KUI}{KUI}{korrosjon under isolasjon}
\newabbreviation{PE}{PE}{polyeten} % Does not expand at first use
\newabbreviation{PEX}{PEX}{kryssbundet polyeten}
\newabbreviation{DV}{DV}{Drift og vedlikehold}
\newabbreviation{NDT}{NDT}{ikke-destruktiv testing}
\newabbreviation{SAP}{SAP}{System Analysis Program {}Development}
\newabbreviation{NCMD}{NCMD}{Non-contact magnetometric diagnostics}
\newabbreviation{MMM}{MMM}{metal magnetic memory}
\newabbreviation{MSFG}{MSFG}{magnetic stray field gradient}
\newabbreviation{ERP}{ERP}{enterprise {}resource {}planning}
\newabbreviation{GPR}{GPR}{ground penetrating radar}


\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\makefirstuc{#1}} % Used for upper case in list.

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype, style=super, title=Forkortelser]

The thesis itself is written here with the first use of \gls{PEX} showing as "krysskoblet polyeten (PEX)" 
and the following uses of \gls{PEX} showing as just "PEX".

The first use of \gls{PUR} however turns out as just "PUR". So does the following uses.  

\end{document}
```

I have not run this code so i don't know if the issue is present here as well. There are of course alot of other packages used in the project but i did not include these in order to stay brief. It is worth mentioning that i am new to latex (this is my first project using it) and don't understand much of the underlying code in the different packages or Overleaf.

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue. Using  `pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 22.3) `  and `glossaries-extra.sty    2021/11/22 v1.48 (NLCT)` ;   `glossaries.sty    2021/11/01 v4.49 (NLCT)`. Try to update the packages.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a simple mistake. The two abbreviations was used in figure text. Even though the figure text itself was not the first use of the abbreviations, the listing of it in the table of figures at the begining of the report was. I simply had to seperate the figure text from the text showing in the list of figures.

From this:

```
\caption{A picture of \gls{PUR} insulation.}
```

To this:

```
\caption[A picture of PUR insulation.]{A picture of \gls{PUR} insulation.}
```